# How to export wave slices to the same bits per sample as the original file

Tags: python, ffmpeg, wave, pydub

I am looping through a large wave file, via a dictionary of new file names, lengths and versions.  The loop exports the individual slices as files:

```
mix.export(key, format='wav')
```

However, it converts the original 24-bit file to 32-bit slices. I have been doing a round trip to pro tools to get the files back to 24, as I can't figure out either ffmpeg settings, or getting the slice into a subprocess.

I have tried several variations of this theme:

```
mix.export(key, format='wav', codec='pcm_s24le')
```

As well as this one:

```
mix.export(k, format='wav', parameters=['ffmpeg', '-i', '-acodec', 'pcm_s24le', '-ar', '48000'])
```

I can't seem to get the individual slices to work in the following subprocess call. `key` is the file name from the key-value pair. This works well in the 32-bit export, but not sure how to make it work when a slice's temp file,  such as `/var/folders/vc/q7jggn7900l099w45463lgx40000gn/T/tmpw_6mxyg8` needs to be called.

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', key, 
                 '-acodec', 'pcm_s24le', '-ar', '48000', 'output.wav'])
```

Hoping for slices of the exact same format as the original input:

```
mix_file = AudioSegment.from_wav(file_name)
```

Comment: *a slice's temp file* --> what is this and how is it generated?

Comment: Hi @Gyan - Using the slice audio feature in pydub.  
For example:
slice ten seconds after a five second gap  
`next_10_seconds = song[15000:25000]`

Comment: This quirk is due to python’s stdlib `audioop` module not supporting 24 bit audio (until recently) - pydub converts 24-bit input files to 32 bit in order to take advantage of the stdlib audio functions

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into audioop.  I have added a subprocess where I convert the folder of files, to a new set of 24bit files.  Technically, it is slower, but works great for my project.